# Script to search and replace strings in a flie

Tags: python, search, replace

I'm new to Python and am struggling to understand why this program

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
infile = open('/usr/src/scripts/in_file.conf')
outfile = open('/usr/src/scripts/in_file.conf', 'w')

replacements = {'abcd':'ABCD', '1234':'bob'}

for line in infile:
    for src, target in replacements.items(): 
        line = line.replace(src, target)
    outfile.write(line)
infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

results in a blank file after script execution.

The original in_file.conf is:

```
testfile of junk

abcd
******************

1234

*************
```

Correct me if i'm wrong, but it is my understanding that the script opens the `in_file.conf` and loads the contents into two temporary files in memory, `infile` & `outfile`. the dictionary type variable `replacements` acts like an array to hold the "to find" and to "replace" string.

It loops over each line then a nested loop goes down the line and loads the variables src and target with the contents of the replacement variable (like an array); then writes the line, until all the lines are written.

Am I way off in my understanding?

The in_file.conf is in the same directory as the script, could it just not finding the in_file.conf and writing a blank file?

I told you i was new to python.

Kind Regards,

Reggie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're opening the same file in read mode and then in write mode (which truncates the file). You should ideally have a different file for the output, but if you need the output to be in the same file, you can delete the old file and rename the new one afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Please use different files for infile and outfile. Opening a file in write mode will delete its contents. Because your infile and outfile are the same files, your file contents is deleted and your for loop is never run